# Data inserted out of sequence when using the Google Sheets Append API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am encountering an issue where the data is being inserted out of sequence when using the Google Sheets Append API. I am using the append API to add data to a Google Sheet.

**However, the inserted data does not maintain the order in which the requests were made.**

- Programming language: Java
- API endpoint: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%7BspreadsheetId%7D/values/%7Brange%7D:append

I am encountering a specific problem related to data overlap when using the Google Sheets Append API to insert data sequentially after merging cells. Let me provide you with a more detailed explanation of the situation:

1. Initially, I successfully insert a set of data into the range A1:F3, and it is appropriately placed without any complications.
2. Subsequently, I merge the cells within the range A1:D3 to accommodate larger data entries. The merging operation is completed successfully.
3. However, when I proceed to insert the next set of data, it unexpectedly overlaps with the previously merged cells (A1:D3), leading to a data integrity issue.

   I kindly request assistance in finding a solution to prevent data overlap when inserting subsequent data after merging cells.

Comment: The URL you provided (https://sheets.googleapis.com/....) is returning a HTTP 404 Not Found.  Can you fix that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example of your code that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.